# How to ignore Gitblit hook per command?

Tags: git, jgit, gitblit

We have a pre-receive hook in Gitblit that prevents unwanted commits from being pushed to the server. The hook logic sometimes produces false positives. It is really hard to make it absolutely accurate. We would like to be able to somehow execute a modified version of the push command that would ignore the hook.

I have tried simply issuing `git push --force`, but it doesn't work. The hook is not ignored.

**Is there any way to add custom parameters to `git push` and parse them in Gitblit Groovy scripts?**

Something like

```
git push origin --ignoreOurCustomHook
```

and then in the script

```
if(someObject.getParameter('ignoreOurCustomHook') != null)
{
  break
}
```

Digging through the JGit documentation gives nothing useful so far. Perhaps I could use `receivePacket.pckIn` to manually parse the whole command, but it seems uber-hardcore and simply crashed on my first attempt to read the packet.

Any suggestions on things to look into are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to experiment a little with a debugger, but it is possible to send push arguments like you want.  Getting them to the Groovy hook mechanism may be tricky.  Or maybe not.  I haven't looked at it.

```
git push --receive-pack='git receive-pack --ignoreOurCustomHook' origin master
```

Once you have something working, you should be able to setup a custom remote to handle this more cleanly:

```
$ cat .git/config
...
[remote "ignoreHook"]
  url = https://somewhere.com/r/myrepo.git
  receivepack = git receive-pack --ignoreCustomHook

$ git push ignoreHook master
```

Comment: I have not had a chance to try it, but is looks like a more straightforward approach. So I'll mark it as the answer. I might reconsider later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`--signed` flag for `git push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) in order to bypass the actual hook logic.

Normal pushes would be done without the `--signed` flag but when the hook delivers a false-positive, you do a `git push --signed` and evaluate in your hook the environment variables [`GIT_PUSH_CERT_SIGNER` or `GIT_PUSH_CERT_KEY`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack). Doing such, you could also clearly identify WHO did the push with overriding the hook...

Comment: A bit unexpected... Thanks, I'll give it a try. I guess it will require some plumbing around CA, certificates and so on. A more straightforward approach would be better, yet this one is better than nothing.